# wget - Mirroring a full website with requisites on different hosts

Tags: regular-expression, wget, hosts, domain

I am trying to make a full static copy of a Wordpress website with `wget` to be browsed without any network connection (all links and images must be converted).

The different requisites for the pages (images, css, js, ...) are on 3 different Wordpress hosts and are always on the same `wp-content/uploads` directories.

I tried to limit the recursion on the other domains to `wp-content/uploads` directories with `--domains` and `--include-directories`, but I can't limit `wget` to fetch only these directories on the `$URL1` and `$URL2`.

Here is the command line (which don't limit to `$URL0` and `[$URL1|$URL2]/wp-content/uploads` ) :

```
wget --convert-links --recursive -l inf -N -e robots=off -R -nc 
--default-page=index.html -E -D$URL1,$URL2,$URL0 --page-requisites 
-B$URL0 -X$URL1,$URL2 --cut-dirs=1 -I*/wp-content/uploads/*, -H -F $URL0
```

Is there any possibility to limit `wget`'s recursion on the other domains to only some directories?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want only directories below `wp-content/uploads`?  If so, is the `-np` (no parent) flag what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

```
wget --mirror --convert-links yourdomain.com
```

Comment: This seems like it does the opposite of what he asked; the man page says `--mirror` "sets infinite recursion depth"

Comment: Also, could you tell us a bit about what the command actually does. Simply stating a command is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Think you might be looking for the `include_directories` switch?

From the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Download):

> ‘include_directories = list’
>       ‘-I’ option accepts a comma-separated list of directories included in the retrieval. Any other directories will simply be ignored. The directories are absolute paths.
>   So, if you wish to download from ‘http://host/people/bozo/’ following only links to bozo's colleagues in the /people directory and the bogus scripts in /cgi-bin, you can specify:

```
          wget -I /people,/cgi-bin http://host/people/bozo/
```